# Magento Add sorting for getRelatedLinkCollection()

Tags: magento, sorting, collections, product

How to sort the related products collection by name or another attribute ?
I've tried something like:

```
foreach ($_product->getRelatedLinkCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC') as $link) {...}
```

but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getRelatedLinkCollection` does not return an expected product collection but a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Collection` which does not support methods like `addAddtributeToSelect` or `addAttributeToSort`.

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184265/4762900. This is almost what you are trying to achieve.